# problem with android sdk in visual studio Xamarin.Android.Aapt2.targets

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio, maui

i have a problem with building simple project on .NET MAUI, i cant see my application on emulator, because of the error: "**Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State**
**Error APT2000 The system cannot find the file specified. (2). PappionMobile C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.Android.Sdk.Windows\32.0.485\tools\Xamarin.Android.Aapt2.targets 212**"
The way my project can be started its only by Windows Machine, but i need it work on android :>
I use VS 2022 Community and tried to reinstall it but that didnt helped, also tried to reinstall SDK, and had the same problem with it:(
I was looking for answer but, unfortunately that didnt helped me.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RfJgv.png)

https://github.com/s1ngleDad/PappionMobile <------------ here is my project

everething i wanted to tell is up:)

Comment: If you make a new project from Maui project template, and run it without making changes, does it give same error message? If that runs without error, gradually add your files to it, testing on Android as add t hem. Try to find what breaks it.

Comment: I tested your app on my side, and the app could be deployed to my android emulator normally. The app works and there is no such problem as you said. The version of my visual studio is 17.5.5 . What's the version of your visual studio? You can try to update your visual studio to the latest version.

Comment: even if i create new project, anyway gives the same problem, its locating on disk C my project located on disk D, i dont even know how to solve the problem, i tried reinstall VS and MAUI but that didnt do nothing

Comment: You can try to create another emulator and try again.

Comment: creating another emulator didnt helped at all, its still same problem

Comment: can somebody build my project and send me working APK file please? it really will help me

Comment: You can try to repair your visual studio. Please check document [Repair Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/repair-visual-studio?view=vs-2022).

Answer (score 0):

You probably have the project in a path with non-ascii characters.

I have tried running your project from two paths:

Runs fine: `C:\Development\PappionMobile-master`

APT2000 error: `C:\RaúlDíaz\PappionMobile-master` (note the accented ú and í characters)

there is a ticket on github regarding this issue: https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/5957